# Problem with migrations using Volo ABP for MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net-core, abp

I recently downloaded a project from [abp.io](https://abp.io/get-started) using the following configurations:

```
Project Type: Application
UI Framework: Angular
Database Provider: Entity Framework Core
Separate Identity Server: Yes
```

I am getting the following error in Package Mangager Console while updating database.

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'Value' used in key specification without a key length
```

Below is the migration script:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "IdentityServerApiSecrets",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Type = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 250, nullable: false),
                Value = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 4000, nullable: false),
                ApiResourceId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                Description = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 2000, nullable: true),
                Expiration = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_IdentityServerApiSecrets", x => new { x.ApiResourceId, x.Type, x.Value });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_IdentityServerApiSecrets_IdentityServerApiResources_ApiResou~",
                    column: x => x.ApiResourceId,
                    principalTable: "IdentityServerApiResources",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

I deleted the old migrations and added a new migration which resulted as the above script.

I changed the maxLength of 'Value' property to 1000. And now it shows the following error message:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

I tried to run the following script [generated in Package Manager Console] in MySql Workbench. This too gives me the same error message.

```
CREATE TABLE `IdentityServerApiSecrets` (
    `Type` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Value` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `ApiResourceId` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Description` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `Expiration` datetime(6) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_IdentityServerApiSecrets` PRIMARY KEY (`ApiResourceId`, `Type`, `Value`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_IdentityServerApiSecrets_IdentityServerApiResources_ApiResou~` FOREIGN KEY (`ApiResourceId`) REFERENCES `IdentityServerApiResources` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this on your Migration DbContext.

```
builder.ConfigureIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.DatabaseProvider = EfCoreDatabaseProvider.MySql;
});
```